getting duplicate posts on feed. may I know the reason
I am using https://graph.facebook.com/groupId/photos with POST request and data is having message , image and keeping published as true,
We are posting one post only, but seeing multiple posts on feed.
DO we have any message limit to post.
Why we are getting this issue on workplace.
